# Check all check box with a check box click

Tags: javascript

```js
<script>
function chkall()
{
 var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
 var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');
 if(checkbox.checked==true)
 {
  checkbox2.checked=true; 
 }
}
</script>
```

```html
<table width="10%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" onclick="chkall()" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" /></th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $i=0;
  while($i<5)
  {
  ?>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" /></th>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $i++;
  }
  ?>
</table>
```

I have check box inside while loop which is running 5 times. I have a check box above the loop. I want to check all check boxes inside the loop when i clicked on the above check box.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function checkAll(ele) {
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 if (ele.checked) {
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             checkboxes[i].checked = true;
         }
     }
 } else {
     for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
         console.log(i)
         if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
             checkboxes[i].checked = false;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: please consider writing some explanation of your code.

Comment: It's perfectly working but is it possible to select those element with getElementById and perform the same task

Comment: Next time I will surely add an explanation of the code @Shaminder S Aujla